# Significance of window size of FFT

Tags: java, arrays, math, audio, fft

I need to compute FFT for a very huge array. (Array Size = 4198320)

I have a method that would compute the FFT and calculate the magnitude for a given chunk size. One requirement of the method is the chunk size has to be a power of 2.

For a given chunk size, lets say chunk size as 1024, it would calculate FFT and Magnitude for every 1024 elements from the bigger array.

For Chunk size = 2, I get values such as 17.0, 1.0, 15.0, 1.0, 12.0, 0.0, 12.0, etc

For a Chunk size = 4096, I get values such as 2334.0, 166.05, 235.84, 313.74, etc

The question here is, why do I get different magnitude values for different chunk sizes, though the input array is the same.

The input array here is a byte array which represents an audio file. What is the ideal chunk size to use?

Comment: Did you forget the normalization factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two reasons the numbers are different when you change the length of the transform:

- Magnitudes will necessarily be larger with a longer window (it is a summation).
- Length of the window necessitates the frequencies calculated.

There's no "ideal" length to use. Longer lengths provide more "accurate" frequency-related information (better resolution) and shorter lengths provide more "accurate" time-related information (faster response).